# Stack does not find the instalation path in the PATH enviroment variable

Tags: linux, haskell-stack

I'm using stack to build a project, and when I use `stack install` I get:

```
Installation path /home/zeb/.local/bin
not found on the PATH environment variable.
```

While, in the `.profile` file I've got a:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

This does not make sense to me. Should I just export the path somewhere else?